# Join attributes by location for lines

Tags: qgis, line, attribute-joins

I have two line shapefiles in QGIS:

1. Providing a road network (many lines)
2. Providing the shortest route between two points via the road network (one line)

I'd like to join the two attribute tables together in order know which of the road segments the shortest routes travels on.

I have used 'Join attributes by location' which combines the two attribute tables, however none of the 'Features they' options seem to only pick up the lines I want.
For example:

- Intersect - picks up all the lines touching (i.e. all side streets)
- Overlap and contain - won't bring across the info from the shortest route shp

Does someone know a way to join two line shapefiles by location without picking up all the side streets?

EDIT:
Example of join attributes by location inputs:
Within the WNP Network there is all the road segments with a unique ID
Within the Route Intensity there is are several lines - each with one route from A to B or A to C.
I'm aiming for an output which tells me which road segments of the WNP Network are used for the Route Intensity layer for each route.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a image and an example of the fields / attribues you want join?

Comment: @Xeppit I have edited the original post as I wasn't sure how to add photos to comments. Hopefully this clarifies! Let me know if you need further info.

Comment: In general contain should do the job, if your geometry is topological correct, that means the have really the same geometry. I'm not sure what you mean with "won't bring across the info from the shortest route shp". Could you provide a screenshot of such an example (canvas).

Comment: Sometimes there are issues with joining lines when the lines don't exactly co-incide. What about buffering the route layer by a small amount, and then running a "contain" join. That way the lines will be inside a polygon.